# Clojure set and hash-set returns unordered value

Tags: clojure, set, hashset, read-eval-print-loop

I'm playing with Clojure recently and I've had encountered some tricky things there.

Why does:

```
(set [3 3 3 3 4 "Sample String"])
```

returns in my REPL:

```clj
;=> #{4 3 "Sample String"}
```

When it comes as natural that is should return:

```clj
;=> #{3 4 "Sample String"}
```

Is there any explenation?

Answer (score 5):

Set returns unique elements of a collection.  Elements in a set are unordered, meaning no particular order of elements is guaranteed (see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set).

If you want a particular ordering use sorted-set (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set).

Since you have different types of elements in your example (i.e. strings and numbers) you will have to specify a comparator to define the ordering, thus you would need to use sorted-set-by (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set-by).